# vuejs: v-on does not trigger function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an input component that should call a method `getUserSearch` when the user types, and update the variable `v_on_search` with the variable `v_model_search` value.

I am displaying the content with the variables: `v_model_search` and `v_on_search` to test, although only the v-model seems to be working.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="search here" v-model="v_model_search" v-on:oninput="getUserSearch()">
        <p>{{v_model_search}}</p>
        <p>{{v_on_search}}</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'SearchBox',
        data () {
            return {
                v_model_search: '',
                v_on_search: ''
            }
        },
        methods: {
            getUserSearch ()
            {
                this.v_on_search = this.v_model_search
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```html
v-on:input="getUserSearch()"
```

or shorter

```html
@input="getUserSearch()"
```

Vue recognizes HTML events but they don't have the "on" prefix